# Unreal Engine app not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Just found out that an app I released back in 2017 was removed from Google Play. I have my project saved, so I repackaged it and tried to rollout a release.  But I have the following Error:

***This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 9.***

I used UE version 4.21 to package the app.

It seems that it is an easy fix for Unity but I could not find any solutions for Unreal Engine.

Comment: Not sure if this helps: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/android-development/1701621-arm7-and-arm64-apk-on-playstore